# Remove the text "In" from the field "inproceedings" using biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex-chicago

My codes are below:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%

\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}%
\setlength{\bibhang}{5\p@}%
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{4\p@}%
%\setlength{\biblabelsep}{-10\p@}%
\def\bibfont{\small}%
%\setlength{\bibhang}{1cm}
%%%
\newlength{\bibleftadd}%
\setlength{\bibleftadd}{-5\p@}%
%%
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\markboth{\bibname}{\bibname}\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\bibleftadd}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}
\makeatother

\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}

Test \citet{abernethy2011blackwell}

\clearpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Content of the `.bib` file:

```
@inproceedings{abernethy2011blackwell,
  title={Blackwell Approachability and No-regret Learning Are Equivalent},
  author={Abernethy, Jacob and Bartlett, Peter L and Hazan, Elad},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the 24th Annual Conference on Learning Theory},
  volume={19},
  pages={27--46},
  year={2011}
}
```

**Output**

[image]

I don't want the text "In" to print before the Booktitle, how can I fix this? Please suggest...

I've tried with `innamebeforetitle=false` as an option in `biblatex-chicago`, but got error...

Comment: Two comments regarding the "innamebeforetitle" option: (1) it is provided by `biblatex-ext` and is not part of `biblatex-chicago` (2) the option does not change whether the word "In" is used, the option specifies whether the name of the editor of the collection/book comes _before_ or _after_ the title.

Comment: @WillieWong Much thanks for your clarification...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bibmacro `cms-in:` appears to be responsible for printing the "in" in `biblatex-chicago`. Its original definition is

```
\newbibmacro*{cms-in:}{% Fix for 0.9a compat.
  \iftoggle{cms@origpublished}%
  {}%
  {\bibstring{in}%
    \setunit{\addspace}}}
```

We can redefine it as shown below to also print nothing for `@inproceedings` entries.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%

\renewbibmacro*{cms-in:}{% Fix for 0.9a compat.
  \ifboolexpr{
    togl {cms@origpublished}
    or test {\ifentrytype{inproceedings}}}
    {}%
    {\bibstring{in}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{abernethy2011blackwell,
  title     = {Blackwell Approachability and No-regret Learning Are Equivalent},
  author    = {Abernethy, Jacob and Bartlett, Peter L and Hazan, Elad},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 24th Annual Conference on Learning Theory},
  volume    = {19},
  pages     = {27--46},
  year      = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Test \citet{abernethy2011blackwell}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Abernethy, Jacob, Peter L Bartlett, and Elad Hazan. 2011. “Blackwell Approachability and No-regret Learning Are Equivalent.” Proceedings of the 24th Annual Conference on Learning Theory, 19:27–46.]

Comment: Sir, it's working fine, whenever I am struck with updation in `biblatex`, you are there to help...thanks a lot....